# Custom Mega Menu with "hover.css" effects (Help)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem with with adding the `hover.css` effects, which I get from [here](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/).

**First**, here is the sample [HTML](http://abovetheline.com.my/stackoverflow/side-mega.html) that I have created.

In the **NAV** **BAR** you will see two `Personal` button. One is with the hover effects and another one is without the hover effects but with the `Mega Dropdown Menu`.

**Second**, what I'm trying to do is to add the hover effects into the second `Personal` button.

```
<li class="droppable nav-item pos-menu hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <a class="nav-link personal-hover" href="#">Personal</a>
        <div class="mega-menu personal-menu-content">
        ...
        </div>
    ...
    </a>
</li>
```

Every time I try to add `hvr-sweep-to-bottom` `class` into the `<li>`, the drop down menu will always gone.

Here's the HTML [directory](http://abovetheline.com.my/stackoverflow/) file in case you want to access to the `.css/.js`.

Hope someone can help me with this, with many many Thanks! :D

Comment: Have you tested adding the hvr-sweep-to-bottom class to the <a>, not to the <li>.

Comment: @María +100 you. Omg I never try add in to the `<a>`. It work now. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @María Quick 1 question, is it possible I can make the hover effects stay there when my mouse are still inside the drop down menu `<div>`?

Comment: Yes you can.

`.pos-menu:hover .hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}`

Comment: Not sure why the OP did not like the answer. I have answered both his/her questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to do two things**

> Remove the padding from the `.pos-menu` element that is your `<li>`. This will ensure the `<a>` tag inside gets full width.

```
.pos-menu {
    border: 1px solid #DF1E34;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Update your HTML like below. The `hvr-sweep-to-bottom` should be on the `<a>`.

```
<li class="droppable nav-item pos-menu">
    <a class="nav-link personal-hover hvr-sweep-to-bottom" href="#">Personal</a>
    <div class="mega-menu personal-menu-content">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</li>
```

> To maintain the hover effect if cursor remains inside the `mega-menu`

```
.pos-menu:hover .hvr-sweep-to-bottom { 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7); 
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Is your comment for me or OP ?

Comment: For you, @Maria answered it first

Comment: I have answered the second query of OP. Please check that as well. And due credits to Maria have been awarded.

Comment: Hello, appreciate your help. If I set the `.pos-menu` under `<li>`, the effects `.hvr-sweep-to-bottom` only inside the `<a>` it self which will make it looks like a pill. For the hover is good, but I wonder that the hover will just directly turn to the background colour before the animation finish it.

Comment: I solve it all. For the hover, I'm using your way. Just add `transition-delay: 0.3s;` to delay the `background-color` then `transition: 0s background-color` and set the `background-color` to same as the `hvr-sweep-down`.

Comment: For `<a>` tag, I have removed the `padding-left` & `padding-right` from `.pos-menu` that you mention to gets full width for `<a>` tag, so I added it into to the `<a>` tag it self. :D